# can i bring 5 foot long pvc pipe on a plane? traveling with lufthansa and aeroflot

Tags: air-travel, luggage, international-travel, lufthansa, aeroflot

Can I bring a 5 foot long pvc pipe on a plane? It is for a pvc bow. It doesn't look like a bow and I'm not bringing arrows.  If I can bring it, will I have to pay an extra fee? I'm also bringing a guitar case as a carry on. I will be traveling from New york to Kazan (Russia) and stopping in Frankfurt and Moscow.

Comment: Do you intend to check this or are you asking if you can take it carry on?

Comment: There's a sign in my local airport prohibiting didgeridoos in the cabin (A didgeridoo is a long pipe used as Aborigine musical instrument). A five-foot pipe could well be construed in the same way. Best call your airlines.

Comment: @ReddHerring: Dare I ask _why_ didgeridoos are banned?

Comment: @sean I don't know. I actually asked a nearby security guard and she couldn't give me an answer. It was on the same sign as a variety of offensive weapons. Perhaps somebody regards the sound of a didgeridoo as offensive 

Comment: @sean I imagine it would pack a fair punch if you were hit over the head with one as they can be fairly heavy, so could be seen as a weapon

Comment: Perhaps check it in using a ski bag?

Answer (score 6):

#### As carry-on luggage

Most airlines have rules that limit the size of carry-on luggage (mostly so that it fits under the seat in front of you or in the overhead luggage bins). To make it easier to check, they usually state the rules as maximum length, width, height, rather than the sum of the 3 (as is more often the case for checked luggage).

For instance, Lufthansa has a limit of 55 x 40 x 23 cm.

Aeroflot has limit of 55 x 40 x 25 cm.

Such limits are often waived for musical instruments and a few other items (under specific conditions), but I doubt a PVC pipe qualifies.

So, no.

#### As checked luggage

Here the limitations is more often the sum of all three dimensions. For instance, both Lufthansa and Aeroflot have a limit of 158 cm.

If precisely 5 foot long (152.4 cm), then it needs to be quite thin to fit within the limits.

Beyond that, there are special oversize luggage categories, but those come at a cost (often quite high, especially on international flights, and even more with several connections).

However, I'm not sure sending your PVC pipe as checked luggage is the best option if you want it to arrive in the same condition at your destination (i.e. neither bent, broken or scratched), and 2 transfers definitely won't help.

So IMHO even if doable, it's probably not a good idea.

However, I would be surprised if you couldn't buy PVC pipe at your destination.

Answer (score -1):

Cut fhe pipe in half, then re-assemble it aftsr the flight with a union joint, which you can probably buy where you bought the pipe.

Comment: I doubt this will work for a bow, as there will be big stresses on it.

Comment: Indeed, this would make it useless for its intended purpose.

Comment: While this is not a good answer, it is not one that a mod has to delete. It will seem a good option for those that do not understand the intended use.